# How to regex search heading to create custom agenda?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm try to get a custom agenda setup which shows top level headings starting with cookies ([/])

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("p" "Custom daily agenda"
         ((search "\[[[:digit:]]*/[[:digit:]]*\]" ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Projects"))))
         ((org-agenda-files '("~/Dropbox/org/todo.org"))))))
```

todo.org contains:

```
* [/] Project A
* [1/2] Project B
** DONE task A
** TODO task B
```

The agenda buffer shows up empty. It should show

```
Projects
todo: [/] Project A
todo: [1/2] Project B
```

Comment: OK, what's the question?

Comment: The agenda buffer comes up empty, I would expect both project A and B to show up.

Comment: And the *question* is...? Is it why? Is it how to make A and B show up? Is it something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using a regular expression to search, your search string must be enclosed in curly braces (you can find details for the syntax of these strings in the help for function `org-search-view`). You should also use two double backslashes instead of one in your regexp string to quote the literal square brackets:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("p" "Custom daily agenda"
         ((search "{\\[[[:digit:]]*/[[:digit:]]*\\]}" ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Projects"))))
         ((org-agenda-files '("~/Dropbox/org/todo.org"))))))
```

With this change, pressing <kbd>p</kbd> causes the `*Org Agenda*` buffer to show:

```
Projects
  todo:       [/] Project A
  todo:       [1/2] Project B
```